# Is it safe to store id's from db in hidden column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im making online university platform . So I have professor dashboard where I can check my studetns attendance and rate them . This table look like this http://prntscr.com/mf33oy . Here I have my students name . So when click button save I need to save data
to

```
|marksheet_id|marksheet_date|marksheet_name|group_id|
```

and

```
student_id|lesson_id|marksheet_student_id|obtain_mark|marksheet_id|group_id
```

I can take marksheet_id and other things from select id. But How I can take student s id ? In table Im takimg students name and showing them . Can I also here save students id in hidden column  and when click save then I can take this id and save data . But it seems not safe . Is there other way ? Im new to php and mysql .

Comment: hi, safe from what? from sql injection attacks? just use parameterized queries and you'll be just fine

Comment: It's not a such problem. Make sure that user can't edit data which is not allowed to him to edit (like professor can't edit group which does not belong to him) Or you can use uniqid (http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) if you do not want to disclose the sequence of ids in database

Comment: It is possible that a user can change hidden field values, but this is more a malicious thing than an accidental thing - do you have any dodgy professors?  [Should I obscure database primary keys (IDs) in application front end?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56357/should-i-obscure-database-primary-keys-ids-in-application-front-end) may be an interesting read.

Comment: I don't think the student ID would be a sensitive piece of information that you would need to worry about hiding from the professors. Most likely every single piece of homework/exams/quizzes, etc done will have to have the student's ID on it anyway.

Comment: @Viktar How would a uniqid help here exactly?

Comment: @deceze example:  by exposing auto_increment sometimes you are exposing the number of clients you have

Comment: But for this thread, imo better spend time on good role-based security

Comment: @Viktar That's something of a secondary information-leak concern, not primarily security related. `uniqid` has different issues in that its time-based and leaks temporal information about records. For entirely random ids which expose no information at all, you should rather use UUIDs. Or just obfuscate them on the frontend with some sort of reversible encoding function.

Comment: @deceze Have I said anything opposite?